# How to restrict the jgit DiffFormatter to java file?

Tags: java, jgit

As `git diff -- "*.java"` can restrict the git diff to java file? What is equivalent to it in jgit? BTW, I've tried `DiffFormatter.setPathFilter(PathFilter.create("*.java"))` as PathFilter can restrict the TreeWalk to configured path. But unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PathFilter is only matching the full name of a file or the path-prefix, what you want needs `PathSuffixFilter.create(".java")` instead, then only files ending with `.java` files are included in the diff-results.

See http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.7.1.201706071930-r/apidocs/index.html and http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.7.1.201706071930-r/apidocs/index.html